# Proportionally scale values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I have a series of values that are percentages of a whole

For example:

- 10 %
- 8 %
- 17 %
- 14 %
- 12 %
- 19 %
- 16 %

These are plotted on a bar graph with the top scale being 100%. As you can see there is lots of wasted space so I thought that it would be better to scale the values to take advantage of the space.

Can anyone suggest a mathematical formula I could use to scale the values into a new set of values based on a 0 to 100 scale. I would assume the largest value (e.g. 19% in this case) becomes the new 100% value.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you just make the left axis run from $0\%$ to the maximum or some round number a little above the maximum.  In your case, from $0\%$ to $20\%$ seems reasonable.  You could multitply by $\frac {100}{max value}$ but it wouldn't be percent any more.

Comment: Although they are no longer pure percentages the relative measurements are just right.